# How to run long running php process

Tags: php, timeout

I'm working with some web services that are giving big amount of data. The time of WS reply has made us to download data it contains (on daily basis, as cronjob).

However I have difficulties with test the script to parse data. Whole script will probably run about 1-2 hrs. After few minutes script gets interrupted. The browser returns a file download prompt (name of file: "name_of_action" without extension).

I'm running this as webserver script, in apache server (Zend server to be specific). Tried:

```
set_time_limit(0); 
ignore_user_abort();
```

and setting long execution times in php.ini - nothing helps. Script keeps getting interrupted.

Best regards and thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If you're running it as a cronjob, why are yo using the browser? Try it with wget?

Comment: are you sure the job isn't actually completed, but does not all the things you want it to do? Thus there is something wrong with your coding instead of it being interupted. Also, what does the download contain? PHP errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to manage long-running php script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212635/best-way-to-manage-long-running-php-script)

Comment: Just to clarify - cronjob will be configured later, now i wanna test it locally

Comment: btw - server is running with fastcgi mod. Just found some information it might affect how timeout settings work. Will keep digging ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still want to stick with PHP for this kind of task, you should consider executing your script in the server shell, via PHP cli.

Also, there are tools that can help you running your script in background, like [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) or even doing it via a cronjob.

Comment: Guess that's the way to do it