# PHP scipts, run through shell_exex, die in the middle

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have a PHP script like this:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($condition) {
        shell_exec("php background.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null 
        &");
    }
}
```

The background script takes about 10 seconds and is supposed to be run in parallel every time the if statement is true. The problem is that, although generally it goes just as planned, sometimes background scripts just don't execute completely. Is there any limit to parallel execution like this and if there is, is it a normal behaviour for the server to kill one process to execute another?

UPD: Btw, if I strengthen the condition, reducing the number of simultaneous processes, everything works like a charm.

Comment: Before anything else, make sure `background.php` does not fail because of its code.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not start a background process like that, regardless of it being relatively short process.

Better to use an alternative proposed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2215188/7689393):

> The short version is `shell_exec('echo /usr/bin/php -q longThing.php |
>   at now');` but the reasons why are a bit long for inclusion here.

Comment: Won't this make my loop slower?

Comment: It should not affect the "loop speed" compared to what you have.

Comment: Ok, I've changed it but the problem remains. Sometimes the background script won't complete. Btw, if I strengthen the condition, reducing the number of simultaneous processes, everything works like a charm.